# How can I set server shutdown hook in Helidon SE 4 (nima)

Tags: helidon

There is no obvious way to do so in version Helidon 4 SE

```
`public static void main(final String[] args) {
    // load logging configuration
    LogConfig.configureRuntime();

    // initialize global config from default configuration
    Config config = Config.create();
    Config.global(config);

    // Get webserver config from the "server" section of application.yaml
    WebServerConfig.Builder builder = WebServer.builder();
    WebServer server = builder
            .config(config.get("server"))
            .routing(Main::routing)
            .build()
            .start();

    System.out.println("WEB server is up! http://localhost:" + server.port() + "/greet");
}`
```

I looked how this problem solved in Helidon SE 3:

`server.whenShutdown().thenRun(() -> System.out.println("WEB server is DOWN. Good bye!"));`

But in Helison SE 4 method `server.whenShutdown()` doesnt exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way.

In Helidon 4, any `Service` or `Handler` you write (such as the `GreetService` in the QuickStart SE example) and register with the `HttpRouting` can implement the `void afterStop()` method (as well as `beforeStart()` if you are so inclined).

The following addition to `GreetService` in that example would accomplish  the same as your example from 3.x:

```java
@Override
    public void afterStop() {
        System.out.println("WEB server is DOWN. Good bye!");
    }
```

You would probably not want to add such a *server* shutdown announcement to more than one of your `Service` or `Handler` implementations, but of course you can do whatever makes sense for you in each service's or handler's `afterStop` code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer makes me confident about this feature. I also tryed HttpRouting.Builder.addFeature(HttpFeature) and it works.